# The Variance of a random variable

Tags: probability

Consider the following probability mass function of a random variable X.

[image]

If $q=0.4,$ the variance of X is ?

I know that the variance of a discrete random variable X is given as

$V[X]=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$

So, here I calculate the Expectation as

$E[X]=\sum x.p(x)=(0 \times 0.4)+(1 \times0.6)=0.6 $

$E[X^2]=\sum x^2.p(x)=(0^2 \times 0.4)+(1^2 \times 0.6)=0.6$

But I think I have gone wrong because now variance will be negative which is never possible.

Please help.

Comment: note that variance is: $E[X^2] - E[X]^2$, I'll let you work out the math, but you shouldn't get a negative number.

Comment: You did fine, and  $0.6-0.6^2>0$

Comment: Ohh sorry yes!!. I am studying since morning, was bit tired so missed it. 
Thanks :)